Unable to run Azure Function from portal
When I run the Azure Function from the portal, I get this error:

{"message": "Failed to fetch",
"stack": "TypeError: Failed to fetch
at https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/ig.js:113:24094",
"isError":true}

Please help me resolve it.
My code is:
package JWS;

import java.util.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

/**
 * Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger.
 */
public class JWSwithRSA {
    /**
     * This function listens at endpoint "/api/JWSwithRSA". Two ways to invoke it using "curl" command in bash:
     * 1. curl -d "HTTP Body" {your host}/api/JWSwithRSA
     * 2. curl {your host}/api/JWSwithRSA?name=HTTP%20Query
     */
    @FunctionName("JWSwithRSA")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "req", 
            methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, 
            authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION) 
            HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Welcome ").build();
    }
}


Is it working locally?

yes working locally

Do you have network restrictions enabled?

Enable access to all networks or grant access from Ip Address or virtual network.

Check the warning in the image

Is your issue resolved?

no, i have enabled access to all networks but still my function doesnt run.

Provide screenshots of your Network configuration and CORS.

As mentioned in comments, this error occurs if the Network access restrictions is enabled in Azure function App=>Networking=>Inbound traffic configuration.

To resolve this:

Enable access to all networks.



Or whitelist the Ip Address or grant virtual network access.



Configure CORS to allow origins:

Portal:

After enabling network access, able to run the function successfully.



it didnt work de to an issue in function app configuration. Now it is resolved

Running your function in portal requires the app to explicitly accept requests from https://portal.azure.com. This is known as cross-origin resource sharing (CORS). Configure CORS to add https://portal.azure.com to allowed origins.

The other reasons you might not be able to run the function app is due to network restrictions.

cors added already. but couldnt run still

is it working from postman? and is there any network restrictions on inbound traffic?

no restrictions in inbound traffic. localhost works fine in postman, but not the deployed version.
